# problems display twitter statuses/user_timeline MVC3 .Net

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

its me again :$, i'm giving my application the final touches, but i'm having a problem, the following code which returns the tweets from a twitter user always returns "Error!":

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    twitter.update('day9tv', 5, '#tweets');
});

var twitter =
{
    update: function (name, count, element)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            ulr: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + name + '&count=' + count,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function()
            {
                twitter.displayError(element);
            },
            success: function(json)
            {
                twitter.showTweets(json, element);
            }
        });

    },

    displayError: function(element)
    {
        $(element).html("Error!");
    },

    showTweets: function(tweets, element)
    {
        $(element).empty();
        var list = $('<ul class="tweetList"></ul>').appendTo(element);
        $(tweets).each(function(index, tweet)
        {
           var time = Date.parse(tweet.created_at.replace('+','UTC+'));
           var message = tweet.text;
           list.append('<li class="tweet"><span class="tweetTime">' + time + '</span>' + message + '</li>');
        });
    }

}
```

I'm not quite sure why am i getting error, and even worst VS2010 wont help my to debug this one, i says "the breakpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document", so i'm pretty much confused, ¿why is the js returning error? and ¿why is VS2010 acting like a douche and not helping me debug this code? :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo, ulr instead of url in the ajax call

Comment: OMG secodn time i have a stupid typo, i... i feel so dumb :$ ... thanks :$.

By the way, do you know anything about the VS2010 problem ? i can't debug the file nor any other .js no matter what .

Comment: I dont use vs2010 to debug javascript. I use firebug for that. console.log() and debug() are powerfull features provided by firebug. Stick to server side debugging in VS2010 imho. Good luck!

Comment: i'll take your advice, but it really annoys me as debbuging for .js was working just fine about a week ago, and today it just wont work.